# How to keep indentation with Emacs + org-mode + visual-line-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Emacs + org-mode + visual-line-mode + window resizing produce this kind of view :

```
* My list
  * Some thing this is longer
back to line which is really
anoying
  * Other thing which is
truncated
    * Sub items with blah
to line
```

I would rather prefer this :

```
* My list
  * Some thing this is longer
    back to line which is 
    really anoying
  * Other thing which is
    truncated
    * Sub items with blah
      to line
```

Any clue about how to configure emacs or org-mode to achieve that would be really really appreciated :)

(emacs23.1 on ubuntu karmic)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a new enough version of org-mode, `M-x customize-variable org-indent-mode` should do.  There's a recent [fix](http://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg19713.html) reconciliating `org-indent-mode` with `visual-line-mode`.

Comment: Thank you very much. 

Indeed building org-mode from its git sources provides org-indent-mode which provide this feature!

Answer (score 31):

Activate [`org-indent-mode`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Clean-view.html). One way is to add a hook

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (org-indent-mode t))
          t)
```

but the easier way is to customize `org-startup-indented` to be non-nil.

Note that even when `org-indent-mode` is non-nil, headlines still don't enjoy auto-fill treatment. It's only the *body* of an entry that will be both filled and indented left-justified against its parent heading's left column.

Comment: Thank you! Needed proper hook syntax for making visual-line-mode automatic for all Org files.