# Can emacs longlines-mode or visual-line-mode be made to respect indentation and lists?

Tags: emacs

I use emacs to edit most of my answers for SO, and although I use longlines-mode (I have not upgraded to emacs 23 because of some critical bugs that don't look like being fixed any time soon), I can't find a way to get longlines-mode to respect the indentation used for Markdown.  I would really like to fix this, but I want it for an ordinary buffer, not for `org-mode` (as [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771981/how-to-keep-indentation-with-emacs-org-mode-visual-line-mode)).

Does anybody have suggestions on how I can get `longlines-mode` to indent wrapped lines?  I am definitely willing to try hacking the Emacs Lisp, although my Emacs Lisp is pretty rusty...

Comment: I've started using longlines-mode more and more recently, and this drives me batty!

Comment: FWIW, SO accepts broken lines just fine.  One newline = space.  Two newlines = new paragraph.  So if you just use auto-fill mode (or fill yourself), everything works normally.

Comment: Lots of other web-based life forms *don't* accept broken lines.   So I'm still hoping for an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked through the source code of longlines.el. There doesn't seem to be any hook there to have the wrapped lines indented. If you want to do this, you'll need to write a bit of elisp (and, more importantly, understand all of the functions for doing text-properties.)

Comment: Ouch!  Sounds painful, but the pointer to text-properties is definitely worth +1.  Maybe it's time to switch to [Yi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yi_(editor))

Comment: What about visual-line-mode (as the title of the question asks)?