# How to wrap lists with proper indentation when using org-indent-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Org-mode I can get headlines wrap with proper indentation [by using `org-indent-mode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1775080/789593). How can I do the same for lists, that is, how can I make it so that lists in Org-mode wrap with proper indentation?

If I insert

```
* Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line
- Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line
```

into an Org-mode buffer with `org-indent-mode` I get the following:

```
* Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
  very very very very long line
  - Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
  very very very very long line.
```

Note that the second line of the list (the one starting with `-`) is not properly indented because it should align with the first letter of the start of the list. What I would expect is the following:

```
* Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
  very very very very long line
  - Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
    very very very very long line.
```

I am running Org-mode 7.6 in GNU Emacs 23.3.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This now seems to be the standard in `Org-mode  version 7.8.03`. The news for the release of 7.8 stated that `org-ident.el` had been refactored for some improvements when used with visual-line-mode (and should be faster).

As a test I ran `emacs -q` and used `Org-mode version 7.7` that comes with emacs24. It showed the undesired behaviour. Adding my local copy of 7.8 to my load-path and reloading org then refreshing the buffer `C-c C-c` on:

```
#+STARTUP: indent
```

added the extra spaces on additonal lines so that indentation matched what you expect.

Upgrading to 7.8.03 (or to current git-head) will provide you with the desired functionality.

---

#### Test results

Org-Mode 7.7

```
#+STARTUP: indent

* Very very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very long line
  - Very very very very very very very very very very very
  very very very very very very very very long line.
```

Org-Mode 7.8.03

```
#+STARTUP: indent

* Very very very very very very very very very very very 
  very very very very very very very very long line
  - Very very very very very very very very very very very
    very very very very very very very very long line.
```

Comment: That is good to hear. Is it possible to incorporate this feature in Org-mode 7.6 by some minor hack?

Comment: I don't know.  You'd probably have more luck asking that question on the mailing list or by comparing an org-indent.el from 7.8 with yours from 7.6.  Is there any particular reason you wouldn't want to upgrade however?

Comment: I am using the version in the Ubuntu repositories and if there were a minor hack it would be easier to use that than manually updating Org-mode.